# Schedule a C# application to show notification at specific time daily

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, task, scheduling

How can I show notification like that of android and mac, on Windows 7 on a particular time.
lets say I want to show a notification to user at 10 in the morning to open an application.
Is this possible in C#.

I have seen some alternative like task Scheduler, but I want to programmatically implement it using C#.

Any help or reference..

Also do I need a seperate application or I can implement the code in my existing application to schedule it to start at specific time of the day.

Comment: Seems simple where have you stuck?

Comment: Check the datetime if it matches the correct time and then show your notification, I'd say.

Comment: Have a look at [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: Quartz as suggested by oleksii is a wonderful project. Saves a lot of hassle in defining cron jobs type code.

Comment: So, what option did you choose for scheduling?

Comment: I am using Windows task schedular

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to Use Quartz Scheduler. I recently used it in my website.

[Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Have look at [One Example code here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-joblistener-example/)